# How do I pass a class in my delegate function?

Tags: c#

```
public async Task WriteToTable1( TableStorageRule rules,string projectName, Stream lines, DataClass dataclass,
           Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string, string> genPartitionKey,
           Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string, string> genRowKey, bool upsert )
        {
            const int BatchSize = 100;
            if( HasPartitionAndRowKey( dataclass.TableSchema.Fields ) )
            {
                genPartitionKey = ( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props, string projectName ) => props["PartitionKey"].StringValue;
                genRowKey = ( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props, string projectName ) => props["RowKey"].ToString();
            }
```

I have my class `TableStorageRule` with object name 'rule'. I would like to pass "rule" in my
`Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string, string> genPartitionKey`
but I am unbale to do as it gives me an error on line:

```
genPartitionKey = ( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props, string projectName ) => props["PartitionKey"].StringValue;
```

I tried something like this:

```
Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string, string,TableStorageRule> genPartitionKey,
```

and modifying the line:

```
 genPartitionKey = ( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props, string projectName, TableStorageRule rule ) => props["PartitionKey"].StringValue;
```

but it gives error saying "Cannot convert lambda expression to type Func(Dict.. because the parameter do not match the delegate parameter type "

can someone guide me here??

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The reason you get the "Cannot convert..." error is that your lambda is still returning a `StringValue` (assuming it is a `string`) while your `genPartitionKey` declaration specifies `TableStorageRule` as return value type. For the original problem: If you want to pass the rule as a parameter then put `TableStorageRule` in the declaration of `genPartitionKey` before the last `string`: `Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, string, TableStorageRule, string> genPartitionKey;`

Comment: Just to be sure you understand: you code receives two funcs as parameter, but you are overwriting the received parameter values with local values. That isn't a good practice. Anybody examining your method and missing those assignment lines will that your code actually uses the received parameter values. That new values won't be visible on the caller side either.